# Apache commons IO Tailer understanding

Tags: java, apache-commons-io, apache-tailer

We are planning to use Apache Commons IO Tailer for real time log parsing. I want to understand how Tailer works internally, as if i specify delay parameter as 500msec and keys are continuously getting generated and at a very high rate, then will it be able to solve the purpose.

Example:

Tailer has handled till x number of line, now it waits for 500 msec and comes again.

Question:

1. Does it start from the line it was on previously or it starts
   from first line each time.
2. And how does Tailer behaves on file
   in which data is getting generated in real time, will it continue to
   tail the file and never stop tailing (and in this situation delay
   will never come into picture)

Comment: If you want to know how it "works internally", then read the source code: https://github.com/apache/commons-io/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.java

Comment: Apache tailer tails the file until it gets EOF and then wait for time specified by delay and then start from the last line read and again tail the file till EOF

Answer (score 0):

Apache tailer tails the file until it gets EOF and then wait for time specified by delay and then start from the last line read and again tail the file till  and so on